# Versions problem with custom app and scdf

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm new to scdf, I've set up a local server, with the help of a guide
[text](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/installation/local/docker/)
my docker-compose custom env with which it rises

```
services:
  dataflow-server:
    environment:
      - maven.remote-repositories.repo1.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.remote-repositories.springRepo.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.local-repository=/home/cnb/.m2/repository
      - JAVA_VERSION=17
      - BP_JVM_VERSION=-jdk17 
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\.m2:/home/cnb/.m2

  skipper-server:
    environment:
      - maven.remote-repositories.repo1.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.remote-repositories.springRepo.url=https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
      - maven.local-repository=/home/cnb/.m2/repository
      - JAVA_VERSION=17
      - BP_JVM_VERSION=-jdk17
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\user\.m2:/home/cnb/.m2
```

and yes, the problem is that when I register my custom stream app and start the deploy process, the stream gets the status "PARTIAL" and in the logs it says -
`Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher         java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0`

the custom application uses java 17 and I don't understand what exactly it uses java 11 and why this error occurs, because as far as I know, scdf it must be different which versions the custom applications use, since they are independent.
a custom application is a regular stream-processor jar that sits on my local machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was solved by changing the docker images:

```
springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.9.2 -> springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:2.9.2-SNAPSHOT-jdk17

springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.10.2 -> springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:2.10.2-jdk17
```